# Creating model instances inside a Django template

Tags: django, templates, model

I have an upload page written in Django that uses webkit calls to enable folder upload and list all files in the uploaded folder.

In my template, I have an event handler for the "drop" event, so it can iterate through the files in the folder and process them accordingly.

It would be really nice to create model instances for each of these files as this iteration happens. Is this possible within the javascript code block inside the template?

Maybe I should write a custom tag to do this? Just not sure if there is an easier way to call `MyModel.objects.create(opts)` from inside a template and have it do the right thing.

Would really appreciate inputs or any examples. Thanks!

Comment: you cannot do it from within a template. In the `MTV` structure of django, you would not be able to access the Model from the template. It would have to be through the view. 

You can use `ajax` calls to views to achieve the same

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Looks like I will need to do some reading on how to do this, since I have not done something similar to this before. But your response points in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you cannot do that from the "Tempalte", but i recomend to you build this using AJAX, your Js code will get the data from the html and then send that data to an URL and so, your View will receive that Data and create your instances and after that your view will return a HttpResponse to your js code.

Comment: Thanks Luan! I am going to try this approach, which sounds similar to what karthikr suggested, and report back